Can a nowhere dense subset contain isolated points?
I found a statement from this post and this exercise set:

Nowhere dense subsets cannot contain isolated points.

I doubt if this statement is true: Consider the real line $\mathbb{R}$. The finite subset $\{0,1\}$ is nowhere dense there, but being discrete, every of its points is always isolated.
It seems that my previous counterexample sort of makes sense, so I'm afraid that the initial statement was intended to say "a nowhere dense subset of space $X$ cannot contain isolated points in $X$." Please correct me if anything is wrong.

@Michael In what topology are the singleton points open?

There is a difference between being isolated point in a space $X$ and in a subset $A\subset X$.

@Michael Singleton sets cannot be open in $\mathbb{R}$.

@Kulisty I agree, but honestly I do not think a nowhere dense subset cannot isolated points in itself under the subspace topology.

A subset $A$ nowhere dense in $X$ can contain isolated points in $A$, but not in $X$. Note that $A$ is not nowhere dense in $A$ unless empty.

@Kulisty That's true. Thanks:)

I think that $\mathbb{Q}\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ with standard topology is an example.

@SigmaAlgebra However, the set $\mathbb{Q}$ is not nowhere dense in $\mathbb{R}$, as $(\overline{\mathbb{Q}})^\circ=\mathbb{R}^\circ=\mathbb{R}$.

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space. The following statement is true:

If $A \subseteq X$ is nowhere dense, then $A$ misses all isolated points of $X$.

To prove it, let $x_0$ be an isolated point of $X$; suppose that $x_0 \in A$. Then for some $\delta > 0$, it is true that $B_d (x_0, \delta) = \{x_0\}$. Therefore, $B_d (x_0, \delta) \subseteq A$, implying that $B_d (x_0, \delta) \subseteq {\rm Cl} A$. This shows that $x_0 \in {\rm Int} {\rm Cl} A$, which means $A$ is not nowhere dense.
Your example would not work because $\mathbb{R}$ has no isolated points. As you noted, it is true that both $0$ and $1$ are isolated points of the metric space inherited by $\{0, 1\}$ from $\mathbb{R}$, but this is not what the theorem is referring to.

Thanks for your answer! In fact, I think your proof can be easily adapted to general topological spaces as well: If $x_0$ is isolated in $X$, the singleton ${x_0}$ would be open. Then in such case, if also $x_0\in A$, we see that $x_0\in A^\circ$ as well, but every nowhere dense set must have empty interior!

@BernardPan That is true!
